# Replace SOQL query in for loop with method call?

Tags: apex, soql, loop

I have a for loop structured in the following way:

```
//MAIN CLASS
for (List<My_Data__c> myData : [soql_query]) {
    code_block
}
```

Can I pull the soql query out of the loop, place it in another class and refrence it as follows?

```
//ANOTHER CLASS
 public List<My_Data__c> getSoqlQuery() {
     return  [soql_query]                       
 }

//MAIN CLASS
 OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();

 for (My_Data__c myData : otherClass.getSoqlQuery()) {

        for (My_Data__c md : myData) { //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            //more stuff
        }
}
```

At the moment, I'm getting the following error when I try this:

```
Save error: Loop must iterate over a collection type SOBJECT:CCDEV18__My_Data__c
```

Can anyone see wht I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loop is capable of iterating through a list. So it's no matter it's from same class or from somewhere else. Just need to have a valid List to iterate. 
The problem you are having is you are not accessing the list items correctly. Your query result is returning a `List<My_data__c>` where an item of it's `My_Data__c`. Alter your code into,

```
for (My_Data__c myData : otherClass.getSoqlQuery()) {
    code_block
}
```

I wonder if it was working when you had the list in the same class.

Comment: Cheers hihghfive! That fixed my issue alright, but another has popped up. I've a nested for statement inside my first for statement, now that one is blowing out. Ive updated my question above. Can you see what the problem is??

Comment: Why a second for loop? As already answered, query result is typeof `List<My_Data__c>` where you can iterate through it. In side that for loop you are having just a `My_Data__c` object and you can't iterate through an object.

Answer (score 1):

List variable should be of type object not type of List. So please try to replace the below code as:

```
for (My_Data__c myData : otherClass.getSoqlQuery()){
  //do your stuff
}
```

rest of the code is fine.